# Weird behavior when using SwiftUI View as accessory view for NSSavePanel

Tags: swift, cocoa, swiftui, nssavepanel

I'm trying to use a view written in SwiftUI as an accessory view of my `NSSavePanel` but I struggled to get it working properly.

Here's the implementation for my SwiftUI view:

```swift
struct ExportAccessoryView: View {
    enum ExportFileType: String, Identifiable {
        // ... enum declaration
    }
    
    @State var selectedExportFileType: ExportFileType = .png
    @State var resolution = 256.0
    
    @Binding var selectedFileTypeBinding: ExportFileType
    @Binding var resolutionBinding: Double
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
            Picker(selection: $selectedExportFileType, label: Text("Format:")) {
                Text("PDF").tag(ExportFileType.pdf)
                // ... other items
            }
            .frame(width: 170)
            .padding(.leading, 21)
            if [ExportFileType.png, ExportFileType.jpeg, ExportFileType.tiff].contains(selectedExportFileType) {
                HStack {
                    Slider(value: $resolution, in: 128...1024,
                           label: { Text("Resolution:") })
                        .frame(width: 200)
                    Text("\(Int(resolution))")
                        .frame(width: 40, alignment: .leading)
                        .padding(.leading, 5)
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(10)
        .onChange(of: selectedExportFileType) { newValue in
            self.selectedFileTypeBinding = newValue
        }
        .onChange(of: resolution) { newValue in
            self.resolutionBinding = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how I implemented my save panel:

```swift
class DocumentWindow: NSWindowController {
    
    var exportFileType: ExportAccessoryView.ExportFileType = .pdf
    var resolution = 256.0
    
    lazy var exportPanel: NSSavePanel = {
        let savePanel = NSSavePanel()
        savePanel.message = "Specify where and how you wish to export..."
        savePanel.nameFieldLabel = "Export As:"
        savePanel.canCreateDirectories = true
        savePanel.isExtensionHidden = false
        savePanel.showsTagField = true
        
        let fileTypeBinding = Binding {
            return self.exportFileType
        } set: { newValue in
            self.exportFileType = newValue
            // update file extension
            self.exportPanel.allowedContentTypes = [UTType(newValue.rawValue)!]
        }
        let resolutionBinding = Binding {
            return self.resolution
        } set: { newValue in
            self.resolution = newValue
        }

        let accessoryView = ExportAccessoryView(selectedFileTypeBinding: fileTypeBinding,
                                                resolutionBinding: resolutionBinding)
        let exportAccessoryView = NSHostingController(rootView: accessoryView)
        
        savePanel.accessoryView = exportAccessoryView.view
        
        savePanel.allowedContentTypes = [UTType(self.exportFileType.rawValue)!]
        
        return savePanel
    }()
}
```

The save panel is presented by invoking `beginSheetModal(for:completionHandler:)`.

It has no problem displaying but the accessory view is exhibiting some bizarre behavior: it seems to be doing its own thing at random (I sought for patterns but I failed to do so).

Sometimes it works properly, sometimes it becomes unclickable (but the function is still accessible via switch control using `TAB`). The alignment is always different from the last time I expanded/collapsed or opened/closed the panel: sometimes it's left aligned, sometimes it's centered (even if I have explicitly opted for `.leading` for alignment).

I have absolutely no idea what's going on. I don't know if this is an issue with SwiftUI+AppKit or is it that I'm doing it all wrong, which is highly likely since I'm a total newbie in SwiftUI. What should I do to get it working properly?

Comment: Try to use ObservableObject view model instead of State/Binding, because state does not work via SwiftUI-UIKit boundary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remembered from back in the days when I was using XIB for implementing an accessory view: I used to embed the controls within an `NSView` and then set up constraints to make it work. So I applied the same idea here of embedding the `NSHostingView`'s `view` within a custom `NSView` and after tweaking it for a bit, I made it work:

```swift
lazy var exportPanel: NSSavePanel = {
    // ... setting up save panel

    // instantiate SwiftUI view and its hosting controller
    let accessoryView = ExportAccessoryView(selectedFileTypeBinding: fileTypeBinding,
                                            resolutionBinding: resolutionBinding)
    let exportAccessoryView = NSHostingController(rootView: accessoryView)

    // embed the SwiftUI in a custom view
    let customView = NSView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 60))
    customView.addSubview(exportAccessoryView.view)

    // use my own constraints
    exportAccessoryView.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // top and bottom clipped to custom view
    exportAccessoryView.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    exportAccessoryView.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    // leading and trailing spaces can stretch as far as they need to be, hence ≥0
    exportAccessoryView.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: customView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    exportAccessoryView.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: customView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true

    // center the SwiftUI view horizontal within custom view
    exportAccessoryView.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: customView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    // usually fixed width and height
    // can be flexible when SwiftUI view is dynamic
    exportAccessoryView.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: customView.frame.width).isActive = true
    exportAccessoryView.view.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: customView.frame.height).isActive = true

    savePanel.accessoryView = customView

    // ... additional setup

    return savePanel
}()
```

Now it works perfectly as expected. Don't know if this is the "proper way" to implement such integration.